# mysql use of in clause throws an error

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM `mybb_main1threads` 
ORDER BY `mybb_main1threads`.`tid` 
DESC LIMIT 0,5 
WHERE `mybb_main1threads`.`fid` IN ( 155, 157, 160, 159, 158, 141 );
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE fid IN ( 155, 157, 160, 159, 158, 141 )' at line 4

Comment: You cannot just make up syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM mybb_main1threads 
WHERE mybb_main1threads.fid IN ( 155, 157, 160, 159, 158, 141 )
ORDER BY mybb_main1threads.tid DESC 
LIMIT 0,5
```

Keywords need to be in a specific order. And this order is

```
select
from 
join
where
group by
having
order by
limit
```